# Redirect to another page on date select using datetimepicker in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using the bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails gem in a Rails application.

*When the user picks a date, I want to redirect the user to another web page.*

A simple example would be for the user to pick a date, and then go to a new page that displays the selected date. What would be the **best** way to do this in Rails?

I'm new to Rails so in-depth explanation (or link to one) would be greatly appreciated!

Gemfile:

```
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.17.37'
```

views/my_app/index.html.erb

```
<div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
<div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM-DD-YY'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bootstrap3-datetimepicker](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) offers you to plug to some [events](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/).

The event you're interested in is `dp.change` (see the previous link):

```
$('#datetimepicker1').on('dp.change', function (e) {
  // use e.date for the new date, e.oldDate for the old date
  // both are moment objects (from momentjs)
});
```

[momentjs docs are here](http://momentjs.com/docs/)